# Insert with openquery to MySql table error: "Cannot start more transactions"

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2005, linked-server

I'm using linked server to connect my SQL Server 2005 to MySql server. `select`, `update`, and `delete` to MySql table are no problem (I write queries in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express). But, why can't I insert to my Mysql table?

I tried many ways to insert:

```
insert into to_kporder...barang values (900, 'testt', 2);
insert into to_kporder...barang (id_barang, stock_code, id_company) values (900, 'testt', 2);
insert openquery (to_kporder, 'select id_barang, stock_code, id_company from barang') values (900, 'testt', 2);
insert into openquery (to_kporder, 'select id_barang, stock_code, id_company from barang') values (900, 'testt', 2);
```

`to_kporder` is my linked server.

`barang` is my table on mysql server.

`barang(id_barang, stock_code, id_company)`

and all of my codes return message:

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "to_kporder" returned message "Cannot start more transactions on this session."
>   Msg 7395, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Unable to start a nested transaction for OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "to_kporder". A nested transaction was required because the XACT_ABORT option was set to OFF.

Answer (score 3):

I had this error also. Tried various things including restarting SQL services and Agent to No avail.

However changed setting on ODBC in cursors/results detail section "force use of forward_only cursors" to off.

Fixed the problem!